# Should we have a banner for potential 11.04 question askers?

Tags: discussion

With 11.04 Alpha 3 coming out tomorrow should we have a site-wide banner to help stem the tide of these questions?

If so what should the text say, potentials links to include, etc?

Answer (score 4):

I've been pointing people here:

- [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do)
- http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate

I think pointing people to those threads would be sufficient. Something like:

"Please note that 11.04 is alpha. See [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) to see what's appropriate to ask, and check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) to see how to get help." or something.