# Can we allow questions for beta releases, while continuing to prohibit Alpha?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When are questions about “ubuntu+1” appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

Generally, Beta releases, while not used by the masses, are ready enough to warrant support by the solid user base who participates in public betas. Can we allow these releases? They are pretty stable, and while they may have a few more bugs, they are not that bad. Can we consider allowing questions about *only the final public (publicized on the ubuntu.com website) betas*, and no bug-type questions(thanks to @jokerdino)? That is, all configuration and setup questions, but no bugs or other hardware support issues.

Anyway, some would make good canonical questions as the behavior wouldn't change too much as the release enters its final stages.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Yes, that's it!