# Asking questions while using ubuntu+1

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions while using Ubuntu+1 (in this case, Kubuntu 13.04) that are general questions about how to do stuff (that I believe are not specific to Raring), such as how to change settings in KDE, how to install software, etc. , not about problems and bugs?

For example, I want to ask a question about installing ownCloud and permissions and another question about the Ubuntu SDK. Are these allowed, even though I am running the development release of Raring?

I've seen [There's an issue with an Alpha/Beta Release of Ubuntu, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do), but I'm not talking about asking questions about issues, just about regular questions that are about how to do stuff.

I've also seen [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate), but it isn't clear enough about what I'm interested in asking.

Comment: [This question on main](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) gives valuable infor about several resources that may be used not just for "problem" type questions about upcoming releases, but other sorts of questions too. Note that questions about Ubuntu help resources *in general*, that aren't specifically about Ask Ubuntu, are better posted on main. It would be unfortunate if this became (in effect) a duplicate of that question instead of addressing the substantive meta issues you've raised. I recommend removing that part.

Comment: @EliahKagan Sorry, I added that part as an afterthought and didn't think about it being off-topic or notice that it was already answered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

Comment: @TheLordofTime I don't think this is a duplicate - as I mentioned in my question, I've seen that, but it seems to only deal with issues and how to upgrade, not with ordinary questions. I don't see anything in it mentioning asking regular questions while using Ubuntu+1.

Comment: If you ask about Ubuntu +1 in GENERAL and are talking about use of it, then generally speaking it should fall into "When are questions about it appropriate".  Because Ubuntu +1 is ALWAYS changing.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Forums has a [subforum dedicated to alpha and beta releases](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427). This link will change after 13.04 is released.

Comment: You may want to expand this. By providing a suggestion about where to ask questions for Ubuntu+1, are you expressing the position that any question that would meet the description given here would be considered off-topic for Ask Ubuntu? (Also, that part of the question is really off-topic for meta; it's a question about Ubuntu help resources in general, which belongs on main, and [has been asked and answered there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do).)