# Please stop voting to close 13.04 questions for no reason

Tags: discussion

There were a bunch of *great* questions this morning in the close queue because they were about 13.04. It doesn't make sense to close them just because 13.04 is a few days away. We're supposed to be getting "looser" as 13.04 solidifies, after all, we can't update all the questions on the site at once!

Please see this:

- [When are questions about "ubuntu+1" appropriate?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

and instead make a judgement call based on how good the question is, don't just write it off because it's about 13.04.

Comment: I only saw 2 questions related to 13.04 and both are still there.

Comment: The problem with creating straight rules is that people will follow them instead of using common sense... Sad.

Comment: By the way, it would be nice if similar behaviour was stopped for at least 2 or so months after 13.04 and other releases go EOL...

Answer (score 9):

Maybe the FAQ should be adapted. Now it reads:

> This is not the right place for:
>
> - Linux Mint, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix and other Linux distributions (try our friends at Unix & Linux Stack Exchange).
> - Bug reports (How do I submit a bug?).
> - Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues).

Are people supposed to understand from that one sentence that there is some room for Ubuntu+1 questions? At present they have to open the link to understand that. The latter bullet could be rewritten to something like:

- Issues with the next version of Ubuntu (Ubuntu+1) *unless they have future relevance* (More information about Alpha and Beta release issues; [more information on future relevance](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)).

Comment: And didn't Ubuntu do away with alpha releases?   Should questions on release candidate images be allowed (unless they're bugs)?

Answer (score 6):

Well...  <strike>In a couple of days</strike> Today we can vote to reopen them.

Unless they were bugs.

Comment: Mod power seems to have died recently... :(

Answer (score 5):

Please feel free to flag questions that were closed because of collective (bad) judgement or are about to be closed (if a mod closes and then re-opens the same users cannot vote again to close), we can have a quick look at them and re-open / clean the close votes if that is the case.

Also, that will make us remember usernames that are constantly showing up on such closures and we might resource to sending a virtual *smack-in-the-head* if needed.