# Often used off-topic close reasons, more default reasons for off-topic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Now that we have [new close reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/195914) I noticed that sites have custom off-topic reasons.

The site allready has reasons for bugs and "not Ubuntu".

But, the major one I see missing is End of Life releases. Another possible is future releases (although those are more ambiguous and often duped towards a target).

I propose we use answers here to propose and flesh out the wording on often used off-topic reasons.

Include sample text and questions that have been closed/voted on with the custom reason.

Note: The default reasons will also be avaible for flagging.

Comment: **This topic/subject is not covered on this Q and A site [please try ...]** would be a more friendly way for a new usere to be greeted than off topic.

Comment: True, but that is not really what we are talking about @SimplySimon I will put up examples "within" the off-topic reason that we already have.

Comment: OK sorry, it is one of the few things that irritated me when I first started posting questions.

Comment: Well they seem to have made it into the close reasons now... confirmation from a mod would be nice.

Comment: @Seth those two "answers" are just examples using the existing ones, The new proposed one is EOL.

Comment: @mateo Oh, I thought I saw the Eol one.. But it isn't there. Sorry. I think it should be.

Comment: @seth If a person votes with a Custom Off-topic - It appears to everyone - so It is possible that you can copy paste the EOL

Comment: @mateo Okay, that's how I saw it. Still, it should be official since non-official ones don't make it into the actual close reason, just a comment.

Comment: yeah, I saw that. It's like *what* why closed?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/313021/what-command-should-i-use-to-list-my-services hmmm, we need an eol colose.....

Comment: Is there a flagging message, for ubuntu +1(Saucy Salamander) questions?

Comment: not yet @saji89 we should make one

Comment: Although I think a lot of those are covered by "bug reports"

Comment: The problem is we are currently limited to 3 custom off-topic reasons.

Comment: oh, are we using one for the "too-localized" replacement @Oli

Comment: I'm begging the powers that be for some more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187549/can-we-have-more-than-3-custom-close-reasons-pretty-please

Answer (score 4):

#### End Of Life proposal:

We have many EOL questions, currently considered off-topic. So I propose we have a custom off-topic reason for them, we should include a link to a question that shows them how to update Ubuntu - Possibly a link to the EOL date list for when versions are no longer supported (maybe even the question that tells them how to add archived repositories)

Qusesions with custom closed votes for EOL so far:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/312850/how-to-install-mkvmerge-gui-in-ubuntu-11-04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/312713/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-feisty-fawn

Possible wording, feel free to improve/edit/comment on so we can get a good version of this:

> Questions about [**End of Life** Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are not supported here and are therefore off-topic.
> See: [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of non-ubuntu questions that are off-topic but *not* unix questions. That should also be an option in the off-topic flag dialogue.

> Questions on **Linux or Unix** which don't involve Ubuntu are off-topic here, but can be asked on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/about). For questions on **Windows** and **Mac OS** or any other operating system, please contact their respective official support centers or try [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There is also [su]  and [apple.se]..

Comment: Point taken. On your suggestion I have added it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Example using existing Bug Off-topic:

> **Bug reports** should be submitted via Launchpad so that the developers
> are made aware of them. See: [How do I report a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)?

Comment: like the other answers, the wording should specify that bugs are off-topic: "Bug reports are off-topic here and should be submitted..."

Answer (score 3):

#### Example using existing "Not Ubuntu" off-topic reason:

> Questions on **Linux or Unix** which don't involve Ubuntu are
> off-topic here, but can be asked on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/about).

---

#### Rewording to include official derivatives:

> Questions on **Linux or Unix** which don't involve Ubuntu or its [recognized flavors](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/derivatives) are
> off-topic here, but can be asked on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: "which _don't involve Ubuntu_..." should we add "..._and its official derivatives_"?

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu +1:**

> Issues with the **next version** of Ubuntu ([Ubuntu+1](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)) are usually
>   off topic here.
>   See: [More information about Alpha and Beta release
>   issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-beta-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do).