# Flagging message, for ubuntu +1 questions

Tags: feature-request, flagging

I think we need a specific flagging message under `offtopic because`, for ubuntu +1(Saucy Salamander) questions?

**Update:** 
Some relevant screenshots.

[image: Flagging page]
[image: Off topic flagging options]

As we can see above, we can mark offtopic based on these available reasons only. We need the option for marking `unsupported release of Ubuntu` or otherwise we need some generic reasoning option, like `other reasons`.

Comment: Yes, please. Mods see also: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6918/often-used-off-topic-close-reasons-more-default-reasons-for-off-topic

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187549/can-we-have-more-than-3-custom-close-reasons-pretty-please