# Are questions about ubuntu 15.04 are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about in-development Ubuntu distributions off-topic or not?

Comment: Most of them are off-topic, especially this early into the regular cycle. What did you have in mind?

Comment: @Seth a guy just asked about [login problem on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/556603/ubuntu-15-04-not-logging-in-how-do-i-fix). is this question off-topic ?

Comment: Yes, that is off-topic.

Comment: Yes is an incomplete answer. I just read that 15.04 is referred to as ubuntu+1. Search that.

Comment: @edwardtorvalds This has been discussed in the past numerous times, and [this](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) is a good starting point to learn more about when Ubuntu+1 questions (the in development release) are on topic.