# Can I ask questions about upcoming releases?

Tags: discussion, scope

I know that you can't ask questions about upcoming releases that are still in development, however, can you ask questions about them when you are not asking for help with them? For instance after certain feature freezes (such as UI freeze etc) can you ask which features made it? Or is this the wrong place to ask?

Comment: "I know that you can't ask questions about upcoming releases that are still in development, however, can you ask questions about them?": I got what you mean, but please rephrase it. "For instance after certain feature freezes can you ask which features made it?": here instead I can't *not* see the paradox; if you know which features have been freezed why do you need to ask which features made it? Isn't "freezed" = "it made it"?

Comment: @kos: Ok, I have edited my question... :D I mean that I do not know for instance in the UI feature freeze which features made it. I just know that there was a freeze but not what got in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the sort of question that *can* be answered and it's otherwise within our scope, it's probably on-topic.

That means it usually boils down to timing. The earlier in a development cycle you ask something, the less likely that is going to be a good question.

There is [plenty of water under this bridge](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate) though.