# When are questions about in-development releases on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I remember speaking to a moderator in chat once where they told me that a question about a future release which is currently in-development is actually on-topic here as long as what is posted is not a bug report. Though I have seen many people ignore this and actually the close reason description, and give this:

> Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu
>   should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and
>   fix these issues.

Even if it is not an issue which should be reported on LaunchPad as it is not a bug report.

However when I went and posted this question [How to install the new GNOME Software app on 16.04 for testing purposes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/723558/how-to-install-the-new-gnome-software-app-on-16-04-for-testing-purposes) I immediately got 3 close votes, though it is not a bug report which should be reported on LaunchPad, nor something which cannot be answered, and as [this answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/14393/364819) does not fully cover this instance and I can't find the place in chat where the moderator told me this, I thought I would post this question just to get this clarified, is it on-topic to ask questions about future releases when you question is not a bug report, and can be answered, and maybe is even answered as a self-answered Q&A?

Comment: If you are interested in testing and development of Ubuntu releases I suggest you run a development release in a test machine and join the QA team - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam They are quite active here - http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427 as the forums is more conducive to discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tolerance for questions about development releases increases when things are known to be true for the final release, and therefore aren't likely to change. Like:

> How do I do X with the new version of Y?

... Assuming we know that version of Y will be in the final release. This is usually around feature freeze but there is flexibility here.

Essentially we don't want to be in a situation where —come April— our new 16.04 users are finding answers that are [potentially dangerously] out of date straight after their upgrade.

In this case, it's going to be obsolete well before release.

Comment: Ok, and it can be closed for the appropriate reason then, but I don't see a reason why it is off-topic now.