# Closed questions which may be considered for reopening after the release of Artful

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen-request

I was keeping a list of questions which got closed as off-topic as they were about 17.10 for past few weeks. Now as 17.10 is released, I think at least some of the questions have the potential to be reopened. Here are some:

[How do I enable 'minimize on click' on Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960074/how-do-i-enable-minimize-on-click-on-ubuntu-17-10) (checked, still doesn't work in 17.10, so the question seems valid) **[Reopened]**

[In Ubuntu 17.10, how do you get your workspaces on both monitors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959865/in-ubuntu-17-10-how-do-you-get-your-workspaces-on-both-monitors) **[Reopened]**

[17.10 file explorer app Files 3.26.0 fails to recognize mouse middle button to lower window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963444/17-10-file-explorer-app-files-3-26-0-fails-to-recognize-mouse-middle-button-to-l) (probably still valid, issue with csd) **[Reopened]**

[Ubuntu 17.10 two monitors different resolution on Dell XPS 13 from 2015](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964062/ubuntu-17-10-two-monitors-different-resolution-on-dell-xps-13-from-2015) **[Reopened]**

[How to disable the on screen keyboard in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960704/how-to-disable-the-on-screen-keyboard-in-17-10) **[Reopened]**

People with reopen vote privilege please have a look at them.

---

Also there were some which got deleted. So I have no idea how "reopen-worthy" they are:

[How to find what is using a shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/959128/how-to-find-what-is-using-a-shortcut) **[Reopened]**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/960919/is-there-a-way-to-get-removable-drives-icons-in-ubuntu-dock

https://askubuntu.com/questions/962372/how-to-turn-off-shortcuts-in-new-ubuntu-dock

https://askubuntu.com/questions/962611/how-to-remove-gnome-from-ubuntu-17-10

https://askubuntu.com/questions/962779/ubuntu-17-10-how-to-re-position-windows-from-shell

Comment: It is hard to field questions about Ubuntu +1 as it is difficult to build a consensus on what to do with such questions. Early in the release cycle I tend to refer them to testing channels and file bug reports. If the question is not a bug or testing of new features, but a general question that applies to current releases as well as Ubuntu +1 I tend to leave it open. As the release cycle progressed I am a little more tolerant, but, if to me it seems an issue that is better served as a bug report I tend to close.

Comment: I have noticed a tendency for what I consider "robo closing" as well, so the problem is if we post a set of "rules" robo closing seems to worsen when we should be encouraging discussion. I review reopen votes and if you feel a question should be reopened vote to reopen.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with the tone of Byte's answer, on a couple of counts:

- There's a *ton* of on-topic space around pre-release Ubuntu. The benchmark is "Can it be answered and will it likely still apply come release?"
- Reopening a good question is not comparable to closing something that's no longer on-topic. One action makes the site better, the other is a waste of everybody's time.

The problem worth considering here is with Ubuntu's Gnome Shell integration being *so* new, and iterating *so* fast right in front of us (not upstream), where do some of these really lie? Some of them definitely read as bug reports in something that could well be fixed by release.

I've reopened and even undeleted a few of these based on my own hand wringing. Others might want to rescue some more. Again, reopening a good question isn't a bad thing.

Answer (score -2):

I believe that **no** question about 17.10 (or any other version) that was correctly closed because it was posted while that version was not yet officially released should be reopened.

That is, **unless** the OP edits and updates it, stating that **now** the problem still persists in the released version.

---

We also follow a similar policy with closing questions about releases which are now EOL (reached the end of their support lifecycle): it gets closed if the mentioned release was EOL at the time of posting, ignoring its current state.

Again there is the exception that questions which are clearly not specific to the EOL release may stay and should rather get the version tag/mention removed.

Comment: *"I believe that **no** question posted about 17.10 (or any other version) while it was not yet officially released should be reopened."* What about questions about 17.10 that were posted before it was released but that were on-topic when they were posted (yet wrongly closed)? [Our *actual* policy about Ubuntu+1, which the help links to, does *not* prohibit all questions about unreleased versions of Ubuntu.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/871/when-are-questions-about-ubuntu1-appropriate)

Comment: @EliahKagan You have a point there, I adapted my first statement to what you said.