# Questions referring to a development version which has nothing to do with development at all

Tags: discussion

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1261122/clear-swap-on-every-shutdown) question, and it has already started receiving closed votes because the author mentioned (s)he is using a development version of Ubuntu. However, the question has nothing to do with the development version at all, and this is valid for most other recent versions of Ubuntu.

Maybe, instead of closing the question, it can be edited to fit a supported version of Ubuntu?

Also, the answer should address the supported version of Ubuntu (maybe, OP can be pointed out that this solution is supposed to work in the development version as well, and (s)he may be encouraged to open a bug report if it does not work, because, this question is not a "Bug report" or a "problem" "with the development version of Ubuntu", which certainly "should be reported on Launchpad".

Comment: Related: [When are questions about “ubuntu+1” appropriate?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/816190).